# creating random complex number in tcl

Tags: tcl

Hi I want to generate a complex number in tcl script that has a form of z = a + bi where a the real part of the complex number is a "random number" as well as the imaginary part b.

Is it possible to call complex function or something like that like I have used rand() and take input from two random components generated as Real and Imag and create a complex number z.  Below is the trial code i am trying to work on.

---

```
set mymin 2
set mymax 10

proc myRealImag { mymin mymax} {    
    set mymin 2
    set mymax 10

    for { set i 0 } { $i < $mymax } { incr i } {
        set realres [expr int(rand() * ($mymax - $mymin)) + $mymin]
        set imagres [expr int(rand() * ($mymax - $mymin)) + $mymin]
        puts " Real value is $realres"
        puts " Imaginary value is $imagres"
        set compNo [expr ?????????]
        puts "Complex Number is $compNo"
        puts "\n"
    }

    return realres,imagres
}

#Run the procedure

myRealImag $mymin $mymax
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend taking a look at the TCL Math library, and at the math::complexnumbers package in particular. See http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/tcllib/math/qcomplex.html